# Optimize select query on huge database

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, optimization

I am developing an SQL query using a Join based on two tables, Table 1 and Table 2. RDBMS is SQL Server. Both tables have a common `ID` column, based on which the join will be formed. There is also a datetime column in both the columns.

**Objective**: I want to retrieve all the rows from Table2 where `Table2.datetime` is within range of 1 minute of `Table1.datetime`.

**Note**: I do not have write permission for the database so indexing is not an option for me.

I got the query right. It is working correctly; however, the database is huge. If I want to retrieve data from the last 15 days, it takes forever.

Is there a better way to do it?

Here is the query

```
SELECT
    A.Column1, A.Column2,
    A.Column3, A.Column4,
    A.Column5, A.Column6,
    A.Column7, A.Column8,
    A.Column9, A.Column10, A.Column11, 
    B.Column1, B.Column2,
    B.Column3, B.Column4, B.Column5 
FROM 
    TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B
WHERE 
    A.CommonColumn = B.CommonColumn 
    AND B.DateTime BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -1, A.DateTime) 
                       AND DATEADD(minute, 1, A.DateTime)
    AND A.DateTime BETWEEN GETDATE() - 15 AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: [Stop using old style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: You can perhaps precalculate `getdate()-15` and plug it in as a constant. Otherwise, I'm afraid you don't have permission to optimize the situation.

Comment: questions seeking performance help should include DDL,DML Of the tables involved along with test data..if your test data is large,try scripting out schema and stats for the table(`right click database->generate scripts->select specific database objects->in next screen select advanced and choose Script statistics)` and paste it in question..With this info any one repro the same issue you are facing.Otherwise it becomes very difficult to answer your question .Pasting server version also helps

Comment: @TheGameiswar don't forget the execution plan.

Comment: If user can provide test data and version ,that will be fine in most cases,yes but adding execution plan as xml also helps instantly

Comment: @Jay Everyone has a different idea as to what would constitute a "huge" database, that being the case, it would be beneficial to include certain metrics. How large is the total DB, how many fields are there in these tables, how large is the expected result set (amount of rows) what indexes exist at this time for these tables?

Comment: You might want to try and pre-select table1 into a temporary table (or even a table variable). In some cases this technique helps. However, it's impossible to give a correct answer with so many details missing from the question.

Comment: Sorry for giving incomplete information. But It is not possible for me to give script statistics as it may violate company rule about sensitive data sharing. However, I will try to give as much information as possible. 
Database - SQL Server 2014 

Number of columns in Table 1 – 8
Total Number of rows in Table 1 – 6380609

Number of columns in Table 2 – 15
Total Number of rows in Table 2 – 32834521

I do not see any indexes. I expect approx. 18495000 records for 15 days.

Comment: Also: **do not** use `GETDATE() - 15` - what is this really? Current date minus 15 ....... what?!?!?! Minutes? Seconds? Years? This is very unclear and confusing - use `DATEADD` and specify **exactly** 15 ***what*** you're removing from the current date....

Comment: If you can't give statistics, there are no indexes, *and* you have no ability to create indexes, questions about performance are more or less moot. This query is simple enough that there almost certainly won't be any clever rewrite that will get you more performance. The only thing you could still exploit is temp tables (where you are free to add indexes). For instance, is the `JOIN` fast enough if you remove the time criterion? If so, you could select the results in a temp table, index the times, then do the full query. This is a poor man's substitute for proper indexing, though.

Comment: Also, if the join *isn't* fast enough when you remove the time criterion (try a simple `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.CommonColumn = Table2.CommonColumn`) you can stop right there: if that can't be done efficiently, and the `DateTime` columns have no indexes and can't be indexed, there's no way your query will ever perform. At least index the join columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try to filter your data first to reduce the number of records before applying the minute condition 
also define variable for the startDate and endDate and use them in the query like below.(Hope it helps, or give you an idea)
(I'm afraid about CTE performance , but lets try)

```
Declare @startDate Datetime =GetDate()-15;
Declare @endDate Datetime=GetDate();

;with filteredDataA as (
SELECT A.CommonColumn,A.DateTime,
    A.Column1, A.Column2,
    A.Column3, A.Column4,
    A.Column5, A.Column6,
    A.Column7, A.Column8,
    A.Column9, A.Column10, A.Column11
FROM 
    TABLE1 A
where A.DateTime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
),
filteredDataB as (
Select B.CommonColumn,B.DateTime,
B.Column1, B.Column2,
B.Column3, B.Column4, B.Column5
From Table2 B
where B.DateTime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
)

Select A.Column1, A.Column2,
    A.Column3, A.Column4,
    A.Column5, A.Column6,
    A.Column7, A.Column8,
    A.Column9, A.Column10, A.Column11, 
    B.Column1, B.Column2,
    B.Column3, B.Column4, B.Column5

    from filteredDataA A left join filteredDataB  B on A.commonColumn=B.CommonColumn
    and B.DateTime BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -1, A.DateTime) 
                        AND DATEADD(minute, 1, A.DateTime)
```

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, using CTEs will not cause the optimizer to split the query in "phases" per the CTE definitions. The queries will be folded back into the main query as if you had substituted them in textually as subqueries, then the whole is optimized. This does not "filter the data first" any more than the original query would (or wouldn't, depending on what the optimizer thought worked best). That's fortunate in most cases, otherwise a query like this could make no use of indexes on the original tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the second clause

```
WHERE 
A.CommonColumn = B.CommonColumn 
--AND B.DateTime BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -1, A.DateTime) 
--                   AND DATEADD(minute, 1, A.DateTime)
AND ABS(DateDiff(mi, A.DateTime, B.DateTime)) <= 1
AND A.DateTime BETWEEN GETDATE() - 15 AND GETDATE()
```